# Textbox Restrictions(Special chars/Numeric etc) not working for selenium automated test execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am testing a web application where certain text fields have restrictions based on requirements (eg.Amount textfield disallows alphabets and special characters & Name textfield disallows Numeric and special characters.), So while trying manually in a browser the restrictions work fine. But while automating the same testcase such textfields accept all data(eg. alphabets(lowercase and upper case),digits,special characters.)...Means in automation no restricton works at all..I am writing automated tests using Selenium in Eclipse(testNG framework) and using SeleniumRC to run tests.

Comment: So i would like to know how using selenium I can still utilize the restrictions in place..Because at this time for automation the field restriction does not work..

Comment: @Slanec can u look in to it .....  Thanks

Comment: 1.Try to send a tab key after you type into this field.  It might be that the field gets cleared, which can be a verification.This behavior may or may not be:)
2.Switch to webdriver, since it simulates user behavior more appropriately. AFAIK it wouldn't allow you to enter the values that are not expected.
As such in any application the restrictions should not just be at browser end, there should be server side validation as well.  You can press the submit button and then validate that output(though this is a completely different verification - kind of a request tampering attack simulation :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use RegExps for verifying strings format.
 e.g. my veryfying of build version format

```
@Test
    public void buildVersionFormatVerify() throws IOException {

    String buildVersion = findElementByCssSelector("home.buildversion.label").getText().trim();
    String extractedVer;
    extractedVer = buildVersion.substring(buildVersion.indexOf(':')+1,buildVersion.length()).trim();

    Assert.assertTrue("build version does not match regexp",extractedVer.matches("\\d.\\d\\s.\\s\\d{2}"));

}
```

another approach can be the following:
you enter a certain string which does not satisfy input format accordingly to functional spec. Then you can trigger somhow that input was accepted (no error messages appears or validator has not handled inproper input) and you can block the 'accepted input' not following to functional spec with assert
e.g.

```
 Assert.assertFalse("improper input format",isElementPresent(By.xpath(...xpath of the error message...)));
```

IMHO, it is my vision of solution to this issue.